# Number of times the waiting thread will be executed

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, threadpool

Suppose I have two thread T1 and T1.

Thread T1 will call `t1_callback()` and T2 is calling `t2_callback()`.

```
T some_global_data;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void t1_callback()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    update_global_data(some_global_data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void t2_callback()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    update_global_data(some_global_data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

**Case**

`t1_callback()` is holding the lock between time (t1 - t2).
In between this time (t1 - t2), if t2_callback has been called for say 10 times.

**Question**

Then how many times will t2_callback() will be executed, when `t1_callback()` release the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

If a thread calls `t2_callback()` while another thread is executing `t1_callback()` and holding the lock, it (the thread running `t2_callback()`) will be suspended in `pthread_mutex_lock();` until the lock is released.  So it doesn't make sense to talk about one thread calling `t2_callback()` 10 times while the lock is held.

If 10 different threads all call `t2_callback()` in that time, they'll all be suspended in `pthread_mutex_lock();`, and they will each proceed one-at-a-time when the lock is released.